# How to fiy onClickListener error in my first app

Tags: android, android-layout

Im new to android studio and im writing my first app

Im following this tutorial
https://www.instructables.com/id/How-To-Create-An-Android-App-With-Android-Studio/

When I add the code for the onClick method i get this error:

```
error: cannot find symbol
        button.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener() {
                                      ^
  symbol:   class onClickListener
  location: class MainActivity
```

This is my MainActivity.java file

```
package com.example.myapplication;

import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.content.Intent;

import android.view.View;

import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

import static android.view.View.*;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);

        button.setOnClickListener(new onClickListener() {

            @Override

            public void onClick(View v) {

                goToSecondActivity();

            }

        });
    }
    private void goToSecondActivity() {

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);

        startActivity(intent);

    }
}
```

Whats wrong?
And how can I fix this?

All this button does is it should go to the 2nd page

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is capital O not small o

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            goToSecondActivity();
        }
});
```

Comment: ok dude this fixed the build error, but i cant see a button when i run my app

Comment: @redbulll can you show your activity_main.xml code?

Comment: no- how can i do that?

Comment: never mind i didnt set a height and width for the button- thanks your answer worked

Answer (score 1):

it should be new `View.OnClickListener()`

```
button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            goToSecondActivity();
        }
});
```